# How to update carousel ad images through Facebook marketing api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am new Facebook marketing API.
We have carousel ads which are created manually through ad manager, but I have to update images of these ads periodically with new images.
No clue how to do that can someone give some ideas.
I tried updating object_story_spec for adcreative with new image hashes,receiving response as success but image hash is no being updated.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot update the adcreative fields, as adcreative is immutable.
You will need to create a new creative and attach it to your ad.

If you are using Ads Manager, this will happen automatically when you edit your ad.
If you are using the API, just create a new creative, and then update your ad to use the new crative (send the new ID in the creative field).